# What's the difference between AT89S52 and AT89C52?

Tags: microcontroller, avr, proteus

I am working on a fingerprint security project, based on what I've read so far, I decided to go for AT89S52 as my microcontroller, but I got stuck when I decided to simulate my circuit on Proteus 7.8.

The software offers me AT89C52, but i didn't see AT89S52. So, I am stuck between using AT89C52 but am scared if is going to affect my work, since I don't know if they are the same.

I thought about using another electronics schematic software, I am willing to change but don't know what else to use besides Proteus and the Keil compiler I'm using now. What to do?

Comment: I don't use AVRs, but from what I found [here](http://www.edaboard.com/thread68548.html)  the difference is that the 89C52 isn't in-system reprogrammable (i.e. you need a programmer) and the 89S52 is.

Comment: They are not AVRs!

Comment: Indeed, I noticed this but only after it was too late to edit my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the purposes of Proteus simulation, the AT89S62 and the AT89C52 are the same.

Presumably you will be simulating run-time functionality, rather than electrical behavior at programming time.

In any case, Proteus cannot simulate the actual in-circuit programming of its microcontroller models, so you're good.

Comment: okay i try using at89c52 as recommended here and see if its actually in line with my expectations

Comment: what about my source code does it have any effect taking the source code of at89c52 to at89s52 and vice versa?

Comment: @GreenOnyeji If you refer to the datasheets, you'll see for yourself: The two microcontrollers are code-compatible - but you need to read the datasheet for any microcontroller you use, anyway.